# Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have used to RestTemplate class to call a rest service, I am getting the below exception.

**org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [UmlerUpdateRequest]**

The below is my code snippet that I have tried:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
UmlerUpdateRequest obj= new UmlerUpdateRequest();

obj.setTrnspEqpId(equipId);
obj.setLstMaintId(lesseeScac);
obj.setRecLseScac(userId);
obj.setTareWgt(tareWeight);
obj.setBldD(builtDate);

String returns = restTemplate.postForObject(url, obj, String.class);
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please show your spring mvc config.

Comment: I am  just using restTemplate class alone, my project is built on servlets.